# List<Object> objects reference

Tags: c#, object, generic-list

I have `List<QueueItem> QueueItemList` list of objects. I am filtering the objects list by object property `Status` and assign filtered list to `processingList`. If I will change object `Status` property in the QueueItemList list does it will be changed in `processingList` too?

```
        public List<QueueItem> GetItems()
        {
            lock (Locker)
            {
                return QueueItemList.ToList();
            }
        }

var processingList = GetItems.Where(p => p.Status== QueueItemStatus.Processing).ToList();
```

Comment: In addition to all the answers, provided below, check out 
[great explanation by Jon Skeet of value types and reference types](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I will change object Status property in the QueueItemList list
>   does it will be changed in processingList too?

Yes, it will, unless `QueueItem` is a value type (`struct`). If it is a `class` then it is a reference type, meaning that both `processingList` and `QueueItemList` are pointing to the exact same memory location for their elements. Those variables are just pointers.

Comment: So in such case processingList can have incorrect result if filtered object status property is changed after filtering in QueueItemList?

Answer (score 2):

Yes because you are sharing a **reference** to the **same underlying object**, *assuming* of course the item in the list is a `class` (or other reference type) and not a `struct` (value type).

Do note that you have two independent lists of references, but the references in these lists point to the same set of objects.

If you re-assign the entire instance in one list (as in `list[0] = new MyClass()`), the re-assignment will not occur in the other list, but I cannot envisage a use case for this anyway so it shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will changed in processingList too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have *N* references to the same object. In other words: you will be changing the same object.